# How can I avoid a scoping problem when differentiating?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

I simplify my real problem as follows:

I define a rule function as

```
Clear[rule]; 
rule[i_] := tt -> i;
```

the real rule function is not this simple.

I define a matrix function as

```
Clear[hh];
hh[x_, y_, i_] := {{tt, x}, {y, 1}}/. rule[i];
```

I want to define a function `hhpar` that will differentiate `hh` with respect to `x`, so I write

```
Clear[hhpar];
hhpar[x_, y_, i_] := D[hh[x, y, i], x];
```

This doesn't work and I know why. But I still can't figure out a way to write a proper `hhpar`. How would I do that?

Comment: `Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh][x, y, i]` is equivalent to `D[hh[x, y, i], x]`, but now you don't have to write `x` explicitly, so it avoids the problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs Wow! So quick! Thank you very much! This works, and I thought I known the reason, but it terms out that I actually didn't know the true reason is `x` at that time.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of an answer:

> `Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh][x, y, i]` is equivalent to `D[hh[x, y, i], x]`, but now you don't have to write `x` explicitly, so it avoids the problem. – [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) Jul 6 '14 at 2:33