# Defining a function that differentiates another function with rule replacement

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

This question is related to the question I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52146/how-can-i-avoid-a-scoping-problem-when-differentiating). In that question, I thought I have simplified my original problem into an equivalent concise version, but I found that it is not. So I decided to open this question.

The goal is the same that I want to define a function `hhpar` that will differentiate `hh` with respect to x, while I changed the rule function as follows:

```
Clear[rule];
rulelist = {{tt -> 1, zz -> 1}, {tt -> 1, zz -> 2}, {tt -> 2, 
    zz -> 1}, {tt -> 2, zz -> 2}};
rule[i_] := rulelist[[i]];
```

The `hh` function is

```
Clear[hh];
hh[x_, y_, i_] := {{tt, x + Sin[x]},{y, zz}}/.rule[i];
```

As suggested by Szabolcs, to defined `hhpar` as

```
hhpar[x_,y_,i_]:=Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh][x, y, i]
```

will solve my [former question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52146/how-can-i-avoid-a-scoping-problem-when-differentiating). But it didn't work in current problem because it only gives

[image: result]

**Using `Trace`, I figure out that the problem is due to the failure of rule replacement before differentiation.** But how would I define `hhpar` now to solve the problem?

Comment: Try with `Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh[x, y, i]]`

Comment: @eldo Thank you, eldo! But it doesn't work.

Comment: define it this way: `hhpar [x_, y_, i_] := Derivative[1, 0][Evaluate@hh[#1, #2, i] &][x, y]`

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

This edited answer reflects comments made on my original version by the OP.

```
Clear[rulelist, rule];
rulelist = {{tt -> 1, zz -> 1}, {tt -> 1, zz -> 2}, {tt -> 2, zz -> 1}, {tt -> 2, zz -> 2}};
Table[rule[i] = rulelist[[i]], {i, 4}];
```

To see where you went wrong let's look at what `Derivative` returns when it is given your version of `hh`.

```
Clear[hh];
hh[x_, y_, i_] := {{tt, x + Sin[x]}, {y, zz}} /. rule[i]
Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh]
```

> ReplaceAll::reps: {rule[#3]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> ```
> D[{{tt, Sin[#1] + #1}, {#2, zz}} /. rule[#3], #1] &
> ```

This tells us quite a lot about what is going wrong.

`Derivative` is trying to take the 1st partial derivative of the 1st independent variable of a function of three variables, and that function is a `ReplaceAll` expression. There is no way that can work, and it isn't at all what you want anyway. In this case, you want `Derivative` to return a function that is the 1st partial derivative of the 1st independent variable of a function of two variables.

Clearly `hh` needs to be redefined to be a function of one variable, the rule index, returning a form which is a function of two variables and where all the desired replacements have been made. While we are at it, we may as well make `hh` return a pure function. This will avoid any possible scoping issues. We will also generalize `hhpar` so it can be used to produce any of the 1st order partials of `hh[i]`. It also turns out that we get the 0 order partial, `h[i]` itself, for free (`hh[i] == hpar[0, 0][#1, #2, i] &`).

```
Clear[hh, hhpar];
hh[i_] = {{tt, #1 + Sin[#1]}, {#2, zz}} & /. rule[i];
hhpar[j_, k_][x_, y_, i_] := Derivative[j, k][hh[i]][x, y]
```

Now we have the situation where

```
hh[1]
```

> ```
> {{1, #1 + Sin[#1]}, {#2, 1}} &
> ```

and

```
Derivative[1, 0][hh[1]]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1 + Cos[#1]}, {0, 0}} &
> ```

exactly as expected.

Computing the 1st partial derivatives gives for all the rules

```
Table[hhpar[1, 0][x, y, i], {i, 4}]
```

gives

> ```
> {{{0, 1 + Cos[x]}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1 + Cos[x]}, {0, 0}},
>  {{0, 1 + Cos[x]}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1 + Cos[x]}, {0, 0}}}
> ```

```
Table[hhpar[0, 1][x, y, i], {i, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, m_goldberg. Your definition really works, but I don't understand why my definition gives wrong answer. Could you explain a little? I think I miss a lesson on function definition.

Comment: And I forgot what this kind of function definition `hhpar[j_, k_][x_, y_, i_]` is called? Could you show me a link which has a discussion on this kind of function definition?

Comment: @matheorem. I don't have time now to update my answer to explain how your code goes wrong. I will do so latter today. As for a link on non-symbolic heads, look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExpressionsWithHeadsThatAreNotSymbols.html)

Comment: I found this works: `hh[i_][x_, y_] := {{tt, x + Sin[x]}, {y, 1}} /. rulelist[[i]];
hhpar[x_, y_, i_] := Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh[i][#1, #2] &][x, y];` While this not works: `hh[x_, y_, i_] := {{tt, x + Sin[x]}, {y, 1}} /. rulelist[[i]];
hhpar[x_, y_, i_] := Derivative[1, 0, 0][hh[#1, #2, i] &][x, y];`

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thank you very much. That it meets with your approval is more valuable to me than quite a bundle of rep points.